# Dependence on column order in response to Smartsheet "Get Sheet" API

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

Question about the “Get Sheet” API, namely  [https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}](https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%7BsheetId%7D) –

This API responds with (among other things) an array of columns and an array of rows.  Each row in the array of rows contains an array of cells.

Can we be guaranteed in any invocation of this API that the columns in the array are presented in the exact order as the cells in each row, and that every row will have an array of cells that is the exact same array-length as the array of columns?

In other words, if we determine an indexed-mapping into the column array, can we definitively use that same index mapping into the cells on each row?

If so, is there a reason this is not documented?  Can it be counted on into the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address your questions one at a time.

*Question #1*:

In a **Get Sheet** response, is it guaranteed that the items in the `columns` array will be presented in the same order as the items in the `cells` array of each `row` object?

*Answer*:

In many years of working with the Smartsheet API, I've always observed this to be true. However, just because it's worked this way until now doesn't necessarily mean that it's *guaranteed* to work this way in the future. In fact, Smartsheet API documentation specifically advises that you don't assume any certain order of JSON objects in API responses. From the [Versioning and Changes](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#versioning-and-changes) section of the docs:

[image: smartsheet api docs]

*Question #2*:

In a **Get Sheet** response, is it guaranteed that every item in the `rows` array will contain an array of `cells` that's the exact same array-length as the `columns` array?

*Answer*:

In many years of working with the Smartsheet API, I've always observed this to be true. Seems like you should be able to count on this always being true, as changing this type of behavior in the API would seem like a '*breaking change*' -- i.e., the type of change that Smartsheet shouldn't introduce without releasing a new version the API.

*Question #3*:

If we determine an indexed-mapping into the column array, can we definitively use that same index mapping into the cells on each row?

*Answer*:

As explained above, this approach should work based on how the API behaves today (assuming that you're creating the mapping at runtime for each **Get Sheet** response). But there's no guarantee that it'll continue to work in the future, as Smartsheet doesn't guarantee the order of items returned in API responses. A safer bet would be to implement logic that verifies this assumption at runtime for each **Get Sheet** response -- i.e., for each item in the `columns` array, read the `id` and `index` properties and verify that the same `columnId` exists at the same index within the first `row` object's array of `cells`.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  But to be clear, I suppose based on the highlighted text above that you can't even depend (technically) on each row in your sheet having the same column order in the cell array.  Of course it would be likely.  But not documented, and hence not guaranteed.  Do you agree?

Comment: True -- not documented, so not guaranteed. But ***highly unlikely*** that Smartsheet would change something like that (i.e., make it so that suddenly the sequence of cells varies from one `row` object to the next in a **Get Sheet** response). From a practical standpoint, it'd likely be very challenging to make their API source code *not* return the same cells in the same sequence for every `row` object. And making change like that would undoubtedly cause issues for tons of customers (since people do often assume order of cells will be the same across row objects, even if they shouldn't).